# Conflito entre Simple_HTML_Dom e funções não Orientadas a Objeto

Tags: php, mysql, dom, web-crawler

Estou desenvolvendo um app que tem que acessar uma lista de sites guardados em um banco de dados, carregar todos os seus links. É uma aplicação de testes mas tenho encontrado uma dificuldade. A rotina é esta aqui:

```
  function crawler() {
      include_once './simple_html_dom.php';

      //Coloquei este registro em um vetor para dar um exemplo
      $sites = array("http://www.folhavitoria.com.br/");

      //se eu descomentar a linha abaixo o erro acontece:
      // $conecta = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

      foreach ($sites as $url){
        $html = new simple_html_dom($url);
        echo "<br>".$url."</br>";

        foreach($html->find("a") as $link){
            echo $link->href."<br/>";
        }
        unset($html);
      }
  }
```

Basicamente o que esta rotina me retorna é uma série de links de dentro da página principal deste site.

Acontece que quando eu coloco a função `mysql_connect`, para poder coletar a informação do banco na hora de rodar surge a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in /var/www/html/crawler/simple_html_dom.php on line 1113

atualizando respondendo a solicitações a função que está (próxima na verdade) da linha 1113 no simple_html_dom.php é a seguinte:

```
function find($selector, $idx=null, $lowercase=false)
{
    return $this->root->find($selector, $idx, $lowercase);
}
```

Já tentei diversas alternativas e não sei mais o que fazer.

Se quiserem baixar o Simple_html_dom para testes segue o link.: http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/

Comment: Poste o código da linha 1113 do arquivo simple_html_dom.php, por favor.

Comment: Basicamento o erro diz que o objeto não foi criado corretamente logo não tem nenhum método.

Comment: Na verdade o método existe, como eu mostrei na atualização que eu fiz na pergunta. E ele funciona se eu não colocar a função mysql_connect() antes...

Comment: brasofilo, para tentar explicar melhor, se eu colocar ao invés de um array com a página uma rotina para conectar ao banco de dados e pegar os links de lá, o sistema não funciona...

Comment: Pode colocar o código que tem o trecho com o mysql_connect, testei consegui esse erro passando um valor em branco para ` simple_html_dom`

Comment: Opa se você olhar eu atualizei a pergunta e coloquei os dados adicionais deixei o o comando que gera o erro comentado.

abs.

Comment: Se não me engano, essa função `find()` recebe um `array` e você tenta ler ela como objeto dentro do laço.

Comment: Opa obrigado pela resposta @luxu, realmente faz sentido, porém como explicar que a função funciona corretamente se eu não inserir a rotina de conexão com o banco de dados?

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object` esse erro ocorre quando você tenta executar uma query incorreta, verifique se os campos que você está buscando no banco de dados realmente existem

Comment: @luxu Não. Segundo a [documentação oficial](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm), o `find()` retorna um "array de objetos", veja: "*Find all anchors, returns a array of element objects*".

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento @GuilhermeOderdenge. Como eu tinha dito, a rotina funciona corretamente, desde que eu não chame o banco de dados.

Comment: Opa rodrigo obrigado pela colaboração, os campos existem sim, a query foi revisada, porém eu nem chego a chamar a query, como falei, basta inserir a função para conectar com o banco que o erro acontece.

Comment: Execute um `var_dump()` em `$html` e poste o resultado.

Comment: Ao executar o var_dump($html) exibiu este resultado:
`object(simple_html_dom)#1 (19) { ["nodes"]=> array(34488) { [0]=> object(simple_html_dom_node)#2 (9) { ["nodetype"]=> int(5) ["tag"]=> string(4) "root" ["attr"]=> array(0) { } ["children"]=> NULL ["nodes"]=> NULL ["parent"]=> NULL ["_"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(-1) [1]=> int(34488) } ["tag_start"]=> int(0) ["dom":"simple_html_dom_node":private]=> NULL } [1]=>` ... @perdeu ao que me parece o objeto está funcionando corretamente.

Comment: Pelo que você está dizendo, parece ser o caso de [marcar uma resposta como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta). Aqui não colocamos "resolvido" no título. Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque como aceita. Se chegou sozinho à solução, poste a solução como resposta. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de achar para outras pessoas com problemas parecidos no futuro.

Comment: Valeu camarada, vou editar aqui. Obrigado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mova a conexão para cima do `include_once()` para não termos desrespeito pelo código do arquivo – isso provavelmente está afetando no *workflow* da classe `simple_html_dom`. Resultado:

```
function crawler() {
  $conecta = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

  include_once './simple_html_dom.php';

  // [...]
}
```

---

#### Observações

**Primeiro**, a função [mysql_connect()](http://php.net/function.mysql-connect) é depreciada. Isso significa que já não é mais atualizada, será removida em breve e você deveria evitar de utilizá-la.

**Segundo**, *preze pela nomenclatura*. Variáveis tendem a ser *substantivos*, e `$conecta` é um *verbo conjugado na terceira pessoal do singular*. Sugestão: `$conecta` → `$conexao`.

Comment: Olha são boas recomendações, mas, no meu humilde ponto de vista não são suficientes para gerar uma resposta.

São boas práticas, mas não trazem diferença nenhuma para o resultado do problema.

O sistema foi resumido e testado buscando eliminar códigos desnecessários. Concordo em ter que buscar boas práticas, mas acho que sua resposta está mais para um comentário.

Mas quem sou eu né? Apenas um novato por aqui.

Abraço e desculpa se pareceu grosseiro. Não foi minha intensão.

Comment: Na verdade eu que não deixei claro onde está a solução. Fiz uma edição e agora está em evidência - você testou, aliás?

Comment: Opa obrigado, @guilherme-oderdenge, apesar de já ter colocado esta rotina de conexão acima, abaixo, em outra função, em um objeto e ela ter apresentado o mesmo erro(kkk), vou revisar tudo novamente a partir das suas sugestões e ver se apresenta um comportamento diferente, só não o farei neste exato momento porque estou em um cliente. Estou começando também, a considerar a hipótese de o servidor ter dado algum problema com o apache, que foi atualizado ontem...

Comment: Na verdade vou pesquisar mais sobre alternativas ao mysql_connect().

Comment: Segui seus comentários e realmente deu certo :D Obrigado.

Comment: @pdonatilio Só para informação para além do  [PDO](http://pt1.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) também pode ser utilizado o [mysqli](http://pt1.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: Sim, mas me interessei no `PDO` por ser multibanco e nativo do `PHP`.

Comment: @pdonatilio PDO, na minha opinião, é a melhor coisa a se fazer. E ah, se resolvi o seu problema, marque! :D Valeu cara!

Comment: Desculpa a ignorância, mas aonde que marca @GuilhermeOderdenge ?

Comment: No meu post, possuem duas setas: uma para cima e uma para baixo. Abaixo dessas setas, possui um marcador em cinza - eis quem você procura.

Comment: Depois de alguns milênios estou voltando a ativar minha conta aqui e percebi que cometi esta injustiça com o @GuilhermeOderdenge e não marquei sua resposta como uma solução viável.

Answer (score 1):

#### Resolução

Basicamente segui o conselho do @GuilhermeOderdenge e pesquisei alternativas ao finado `mysql_connect()` e utilizei o [PDO](http://pt1.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php), e qual não foi minha surpresa ao trabalhar somente com objetos o sistema funcionou perfeita harmonia e sem bugs.

Então substitui o comando:

```
$conecta = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
```

Pela conexão com o [PDO](http://pt1.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php):

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=meuBancoDeDados', "root", ""); 
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

E tudo funcionou direito. Detalhe que sempre que eu tentar colocar uma função fora de um objeto para trabalhar diretamente com o `simple_html_dom` eu vou correr o risco de ter esse problema.

Então a partir de agora 100% PDO 
E 100% Orientação a Objeto
:D

Obrigado à todos que ajudaram.

Comment: É isso aí! \o/ =)